# How to safely escape the input data in php for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Which means, at the moment, are the safest for screening data in php to send them to the mysql database.

Thank, you )

Comment: In addition to the answers below, it's worth reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: And if I use the mysql_connect?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe <strike>[mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)</strike> [mysql**i**_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) is the best way to escape input data

Later edit since everything is deprecated now and information must be valid:

Try to use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) as prepared statements are much safer or [mysqli_*() functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) if you really need to keep old code somewhat up-to-date.

Comment: I would argue passing your strings as parameters to prepared statements is safer.

Comment: I also currently use it to them

Answer (score 5):

Currently the most preferred way to insure your safety is prepared statements.

example:

```
$preparedStatement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM memebers WHERE username = :username');

$preparedStatement->execute(array(':username' => $username));

$rows = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
```

then when displaying your data use `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 3):

```
validMySQL($var) {
$var=stripslashes($var);
$var=htmlentities($var);
$var=strip_tags($var);
$var=mysql_real_escape_string($var);
return $var
}
```

The above code helps to sanitize most invalid data, just remember that you've to be connected to mysql database for mysql_real_escape_string to work...